# Obtaining Mule Variable Values in Java

Tags: java, mule

In Mule 3.4, how do I obtain the value of the *Mule* variable set from the "set-variable" tag in Java? Also how do I obtain values of *Mule* variables in different flows such as **counter** in flow1 and **prevCounter** in flow2? I can't find this on Mule's website.

Below is the Mule XML:

```
    <mule xmlns:smtp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
        xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:mongo="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo" xmlns:quartz="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo/2.0/mule-mongo.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz/current/mule-quartz.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp/current/mule-smtp.xsd">
        <quartz:connector name="Quartz3" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Quartz"/>    
        <flow name="flow1" doc:name="flow1">
            <set-variable variableName="#['counter']" value="#[0]" doc:name="Variable"/>
            <flow-ref name="flow2" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
        </flow>
        <flow name="flow2" doc:name="flow2">
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <set-variable variableName="prevCounter" value="#[flowVars['counter']]" doc:name="Variable"/>
            <set-variable variableName="counter" value="#[flowVars['counter']+1]" doc:name="Variable"/>
            <choice doc:name="Choice">
                <when expression="#[flowVars['counter']==5]">
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <flow-ref name="flow2" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
        </flow>
    </mule>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get them from the Mule message with `message.getInvocationProperty('counter')`.

Flow variables exist only during the flow of a message, so you can only access what was declared before in the same flow (or the flow that calls the current flow like you are doing right there in flow2). If you need them somewhere outside of the flow, you have to send them there from the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Values stored with set-variable can be retrieved with MEL as `flowVars['varName']`.

Take a look at this:

http://blogs.mulesoft.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/refcard-mel.pdf

Comment: I see that this is from within the XML, but what about from Java?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to create session variable or Flow variable in java and to retrive them in java MEL wont support you should use syntax some thing like **message.getInvocationProperty('name')** if those are flow variables.